# IPv6 socket creation

Tags: sockets, ipv6

I am implementing dual stack mode to support IPv4 and IPv6.
If I am creating a IPv6 socket and listening on it, will it accept the connection from IPv4 socket also ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unless the operating system is configured otherwise, e.g. `net.ipv6.bindv6only=1` in Linux, or you set the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option.

Comment: I've noticed in .Net that you have to explicitly set `SocketOptionName.IPv6Only` to `false`, otherwise it wouldn't accept IPv4 connections on the IPv6 socket. Example: `listener_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);`

Answer (score 2):

Only if the system has a [dual-stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-stack#Dual_IP_stack_implementation) implementation. Most modern systems do, but old versions of Windows and OpenBSD do not. You shouldn't rely on this though. Get the value of the IPV6_V6ONLY socket option and if it's zero you will need to open a second socket for IPv4.

When using a dual-stack socket IPv4 addresses are represented as `::ffff:[IPv4 address]`; for example `::ffff:127.0.0.1` (this corresponds to `::ffff:7f00:1`; it's just typically printed in dot-decimal notation for the sake of readability).

Comment: @spencercw...but while creating and accepting connection on ipv6 socket we have to pass sockaddr_in6 structure and its size. So, will it not make a difference. And how to set the value of IPV6_V6ONLY. Can you please explain it how to acheive it in the code. Do I need to pass this in setsocketoption ??

Comment: You probably don't want to change the IPv6 only option. Use the dual-stack capability if it's available to you, only if not then you open a second socket for IPv4. You need to use [getsockopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockopt) to get the value of the option.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the default even in dual stack mode is to have **IPV6_V6ONLY** set to false - but you can enable it through the setsockopt(2) call.  FWIW, "Old versions" of Windows (single-stack) include the still-widely-used Windows XP (anything older than Vista).

So, if you're on Windows you should try and disable IPV6_V6ONLY and see if it succeeds.  I don't know if that's a good answer for other single-stack implementations or not.